# How many ways are there to define a Custom List Adapter for ListView in Android..?

Tags: android, listview

I want to know the most efficient way of defining an Custom `Adapter` for `ListView`. For example:-

1) Is creating new views Under `getView()` method efficient?

2) Inflating from an xml file and setting up from there would be a efficient?

(OR) Is there any other way to do it? I am a total beginner in android development. Please help.

Comment: Inflating an XML file is creating a new View object...

Comment: @Div Too much Inflation is bad that's why there is ViewHolder pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also new to Android development but I think you should use the ViewHolder pattern. It's what I'm using and it works like a charm.

Comment: thanks .. one more thing , which approach do you think is much more memory efficient..??